# Sudo Make command entering into wrong directory

Tags: command-line, bash, kernel, compiling

I'm trying to compile a kernel module with applying race conditions on 4 threads created using kthread_create(). However, when I run `sudo-make`, it enters the wrong directory and doesn't compile the file I want to compile which is named race_module.c which is in a folder called "Lab4". The directory it is entering is:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.179CS630Team6/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/parallels/Downloads/linux-5.4.179'
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CHK     kernel/kheaders_data.tar.xz
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 5983 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/Downloads/linux-5.4.179'
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
    obj-m += race_module.o
    
    all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
    
    clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

How can I make it execute my race_module.c file?
Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd need to run `sudo make` to build a kernel module; the usual workflow is to run `make` as an unprivileged user, then use `modprobe` or `insmod` as root to insert the built module into the kernel.

By default, Ubuntu's sudo configuration performs an `env_reset`, which appears to include the `PWD` variable. So given

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
        @echo "PWD is \"$(PWD)\""
```

then

```
$ make
PWD is "/home/steeldriver/dir"
```

but

```
$ sudo make
PWD is ""
```

You could ask sudo to preserve the variable:

```
$ sudo --preserve-env=PWD make
PWD is "/home/steeldriver/dir"
```

however IMHO it's better to modify your Makefile to use command `pwd` in place of the variable expandion `$PWD`:

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
        @echo "PWD is \"$(shell pwd)\""

$ sudo make
PWD is "/home/steeldriver/dir"
```

In your case:

```
obj-m += race_module.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, additionally, I was missing MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); at the end of my code.